# Add value to excel reference number

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I want to be able add a number that is dynamically generated to a cell reference number such as if a particular cell is may be "**Sheet1!$D16970**", I want to add may be 3 or 10 or even 100 so that the result is "**Sheet1!$D16973**" or "**Sheet1!$D16980**" or "**Sheet1!$D17080**". Please bear in mind that the numbers to be added are dynamically generated by the formula **COUNT()**. The count formula looks for cells that contain only numbers in the previous column. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is what I expect: "*Sheet1!$D16970*" + COUNT(B$3:B$17). The count function counts the number of cells that contain numbers. If it finds may be 5, I want the cell reference to read "*Sheet1!$D16975*". Is this possible?

Comment: will there be a cell that contains the string "Sheet1!$D16970" (or whatever your base reference is)?

Comment: Yes, there is a cell.

Comment: and will teh column always be one character? There doesnt seem to be a good way to isolate the row number except for finding that "$" and then moving a fixed amount over, unless you were to use a UDF to remove non-numeric characters (you would need to do this after splicing at the $ to avoid the sheet #)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

> =INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&A1;TRUE)

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @Maurice Yes, sorry for the late reply. It returns a reference or the value to the cell indicated by a text string. In the example the text string (the first argument) consists of two parts. The first is "Sheet2!A" while the second is taken from the cell A1 (expected to be a number) so you have something like "Sheet2!A5". The second argument means the reference style which can be A1 for true or R1C1 for false. Finally, since this function returns a reference it can be used inside other functions just like you would use A1 reference.